# Max Executor failures in Spark dynamic allocation

Tags: apache-spark

I am using dynamic allocation feature of spark to run my spark job. It allocates around 50-100 executors. For some reason few executors are lost resulting in shutting down the job. Log shows that this happened due to max executor failures reached. It is set to 3 by default. Hence when 3 executors are lost the job gets killed even if other 40-50 executors are running.
I know that I can change the max executor failure limit but this seems like a workaround. Is there something else that I can try. All suggestions are welcome.

Comment: You should try to find out why the executors are failing in the first place...

Comment: Hi Raphael, I tried to look in the logs and it says that executors were lost because remote rpc client disassociated. Can you please suggest something to avoid this. I searched for this issue and found out that this may occur due to lack of memory, but since I am using dynamic allocation this shouldn't be an issue

Comment: Can you include the relevant logs?